# 2018 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2018 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://ell.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: I would consider Michael Rybkin to be a worthy candidate. https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/6450/michael-rybkin If he sees this comment, I hope he considers entering the arena.

Comment: I am very happy that one of the candidates dicided to get up to represent US!. Not for  the satisfaction of big ones!